# Convert Matlab code arithmetic operator implementation to C#

Tags: c#, matlab, math

I have one Matlab implementation and converting to C#.

```
p is 244x3 matrix.

Matlab    p'*2^(-15)*4;
```

In C#, for me p matrix transpose is not necessary, so I don't do transpose. So every element in p matrix, what I do is

```
C#        Math.pow(p[i,j]*2, (-15))*4;
```

I don't get same result as in Matlab. What is wrong?

Comment: Possibly `p[i,j] * Math.Pow(2, -15) * 4`

Comment: Yes correct. it works. Thank you